# mvc dataannotation regularexpression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, passwords, data-annotations

I just started messing around with regularexpressions, but basically with this one (which i found online btw) is supposed to require for the password to be between 8 - 10, but whenever i try it out and put in the correct length it's still showing the error message. any ideas?
i also need to include a 1 lowercase, 1 uppercase and 1 number on the validations..

```
public class password : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression("(?=^.{8,10}$)", ErrorMessage = "Password is invalid.")]
    public string ConfirmPWD { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Confirm Password field is required.")]
    public string ConfirmPWD { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (ConfirmPWD != ConfirmPWD )
            yield return new ValidationResult("Not identical.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

`[RegularExpression(@"^.{8,10}$", 
         ErrorMessage = "Must be between 8 and 10 characters.")]`

Answer (score 0):

try just `".{8,10}"`.  also, a more specific error message might be helpful to your users.

Edit: come to think of it why not just use the `StringLengthAttribute` for this...

`[StringLength(10, MinLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 8 and 10 characters")]`

then you can use regex for your more specific rules such as required complexity.

Comment: well, i have like 2 - 3 others that i need to add, do i just add multiple regex on it? eg. 1 for "Password needs to have at least 1 uppercase character, 1 for "Password needs to have at least 1 numeric character", etci feel like i need to do some ienumerable validation to check it, i just dont know how to go about it..

Comment: this might work on stringlength but for the rest, like 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 numeric needs to have specific messages each, if i place it all in one regex it'll just give me one errormessage, which is the one specified on that regex line.